# How to resize table to screen size? (web development/html/css/javascript)

Tags: javascript, web, size, screen

I am very new to web development and I'm getting familiar with html/css rigors. Is there any way to adjust a table according to screen size yet still keep its original proportions?

In my specific case, I generate a square table via javascript and I want to have each of the cells still keeping their place and ratio, yet vary in their total size according to how I adjust the browser screen (or whether I access the page on mobile or display it on other kind of screen sizes, etc). I want the whole table to become from microscopic to infinitely huge, according to in-browser screen size.

This is how I generate the table in javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
         var mapSquare = document.createElement('div');
         mapSquare.className = 'map-square';
         board.appendChild(mapSquare);
```

Can you please offer me the simplest and most effective solution to this? What kind of CSS styling should I go for to achieve the desire result?

Thank you.

I've tried to set the with and height to 100% or auto, but then the table won't exactly keep its proportions, only vary in how many columns or rows I see on screen at once. Meanwhile, I want all rows and columns to be visible at all times, yet only shrink in their overall size, according to the screen.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it,  but it won't produce the desired result. The table remains fixed and won't adjust anytime I try to resize the window, whereas I need it to shrink or enlarge while keeping its proportions.